# java method error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I have a task to do, which is make a film archive. Here are my tasks:

> Besides the main program, create a custom class that stores information about a movie. This class is then used in the main program. The following information should be stored for each film

```
title
length
grade 
format
year
```

then

> In the main program, you should be able to store 1,000 films.
>   The user should be able to do the following in the program (make a selection menu):
>
> • Enter the information about a movie. Make a method for loading a movie from the user.
>
> • Print the information on all films. Make a method for printing a film and use it.
>
> • Save all your movies to a file. Please do your own method for this.
>
> • Download movies from a file. Please do your own method for this.

The problem is that I got an error with my `skrivUtInfo(PrintOut information)` method

I create an array list of 1000 films. But how can I print 1000 films?

Here is my code:

```
public class Film {
    String  title ;
    int     length;
    int     grade ;
    String  format ;
    int     year ;
}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Filmarkiv {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(inFromUser);

        Film[] film = new Film[1000];

        int antal = 1;

        film[0] = new Film();
        film[0].title = "matrix";
        film[0].length = 220;
        film[0].grade = 5;
        film[0].format = "DVD";
        film[0].year = 1999;

        while(true)
        {
            int n = 0;
            System.out.println("valj 1 for inmata. 2 for utskrift");

            String val = s.next();

            if(val.equals("1")){
                System.out.println("vad heter filmen?");
                film[n].title = s.next();

                System.out.println("hur lang ar filmen?");
                film[n].length = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("vad har den for betyg?");
                film[n].grade = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("vad har den for format?");
                film[n].format = s.next() ;

                System.out.println("i vilket år har filmen inspelat? ");
                film[n].year = s.nextInt() ;
            }
            else if (val.equals("2"))
            {
                skrivUtInfo(film, antal);

                /*System.out.println("title = "+film[n].title) ;
                System.out.println("length = "+film[n].length) ;
                System.out.println("grade = "+film[n].grade) ;
                System.out.println("format = "+film[n].format) ;
                System.out.println("year = "+film[n].year);*/
            }
        }
    }

    public  skrivUtInfo (Film[]  qwert, int a) {
        for (int n=0; n<a; n++) {
            System.out.println("title = "+film[n].title) ;
            System.out.println("length = "+film[n].length) ;
            System.out.println("grade = "+film[n].grade) ;
            System.out.println("format = "+film[n].format) ;
            System.out.println("year = "+film[n].year) ;

            return Film[];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

If you've learned about `java.util.List`, you can do it this way:

```
List<Film> films = new ArrayList<Film>();
films.add(new Film("Amadeus", 120, 5, "DVD", 1984);  );  // Add as many as you like
System.out.println(films);  // Make sure your Film class overrides toString()
```

If you haven't, just do it in a loop:

```
Film [] films = new Film[1000];
films[0] = new Film("Amadeus", 120, 5, "DVD", 1984);  
for (Film film : films) {
    System.out.println(film);  // Make sure you File class overrides toString()

}
```

You're probably having problems because your Film class is flawed.  Do it this way:

```
public class Film {

    private final String  title ;
    private final int     length;
    private final int     grade ;
    private final String  format ;
    private final int     year ;

    public Film(String title, int length, int grade, String format, int year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.length = length;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.format = format;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Film");
        sb.append("{title='").append(title).append('\'');
        sb.append(", length=").append(length);
        sb.append(", grade=").append(grade);
        sb.append(", format='").append(format).append('\'');
        sb.append(", year=").append(year);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanX
i did it but i got  null ??

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the method as

```
public static void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
    for (int n=0; n<qwert.length; n++) {
        System.out.println("title = "+qwert[n].title) ;
        System.out.println("length = "+qwert[n].length) ;
        System.out.println("grade = "+qwert[n].grade) ;
        System.out.println("format = "+qwert[n].format) ;
        System.out.println("year = "+qwert[n].year) ;
    }
}
```

also put a bracket here

```
else if (val.equals("2"))
{
    skrivUtInfo(film);
    // the comments
}
} //<- you must add this bracket. is from while (i think)
```

also a tip, in Film class you can override the toString method from class Object

```
public class Film{
    String  title ;
    int     length;
    int     grade ;
    String  format ;
    int     year ;

    public String toString() {
     return "title = " + title +
            "length = " + length +
            "grade = " + grade +
            "format = " + format +
            "year = " + year;

    }
}
```

so the skrivUtInfo becomes

```
public static void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
    for (int n=0; n<qwert.length; n++) {
        System.out.println(qwert[n]);
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
    for (Film f : qwert) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you man for help but i got a some errors


Filmarkiv.java:75: error: illegal start of expression
 public void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
 ^
Filmarkiv.java:75: error: illegal start of expression
 public void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
        ^
Filmarkiv.java:75: error: ';' expected
 public void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
                        ^
Filmarkiv.java:75: error: ';' expected
 public void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
                                      ^
4 errors

Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: my fault. declare skrivUtInfo as static. and you need to close a bracket

Comment: when i press 2 nothing happened??

Answer (score 0):

The method `public  skrivUtInfo (Film[]  qwert, int a)` has no return type specified. In java either it should have a `void` or a valid type as return, but i see you returning `Film[]`. You cannot do that way. You have to declare like

```
 public Film[] skrivUtInfo (Film[]  qwert, int a){
   ....
   return qwert;
 }
```

Ultimately since you are just printing the stuff here you don't need to return anything. In that case you should have

```
 public  void skrivUtInfo (Film[]  qwert, int a){
   .....
   return;
 }
```

You can have an empty return or no return specified in a method which has a `void` return type.

Answer (score 0):

I have test this code and works fine. I change a few parts as i thought it should play

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filmarkiv {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner s = new Scanner(inFromUser);

        Film[] film = new Film[1000];
        int n = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("valj 1 for inmata. 2 for utskrift");
            String val = s.next();

            if (val.equals("1")) {
                film[n] = new Film();

                System.out.println("vad heter filmen?");
                film[n].title = s.next();

                System.out.println("hur lang ar filmen?");
                film[n].length = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("vad har den for betyg?");
                film[n].grade = s.nextInt();

                System.out.println("vad har den for format?");
                film[n].format = s.next();

                System.out.println("i vilket år har filmen inspelat? ");
                film[n].year = s.nextInt();

                n++;
            } else if (val.equals("2")) {
                skrivUtInfo(film);
            }
        } while(n < film.length);

    }

    public static void skrivUtInfo (Film[] qwert) {
        for (Film f : qwert) {
            if (f != null)
                System.out.println(f);
        }
    }
}

class Film {
    String title;
    int length;
    int grade;
    String format;
    int year;

    public String toString() {
        return "title = " + title + ", length = " + length + ", grade = " + grade
                + ", format = " + format + ", year = " + year;

    }
}
```